# Get container behind std::stack

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using a `std::stack` to keep a list of possibilities in my program.

```
std::stack<int, std::deque<int> > myStack;
```

Now, for **debugging purposes** only, I want to have access to all the elements of my `std::stack` (for instance as a `std::deque`). But the following syntax is illegal:

```
std::deque<int> myDeque = myStack; // Does not compile
```

What is the simplest way to do it?

---

The way I would do it is:

```
std::stack<int, std::deque<int> > newStack = myStack;
std::deque<int> myDeque;
while(!newStack.empty()){
    myDeque.push_back(newStack.top());
    newStack.pop();
}
```

but it looks a bit ugly.

Answer (score 11):

The underlying container of `std::stack` is accessible as protected member [`c`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack). Hence:

```
template<class T, class C>
struct MyStack : std::stack<T, C> 
{
    typedef std::stack<T, C> Stack;
    using Stack::Stack;
    using Stack::operator=;
    using Stack::c; // expose as public
};
```

And if you cannot change definitions and recompile, then:

```
template<class T, class C>
C& get_underlying_container(std::stack<T, C>& s) {
    static_assert(sizeof s == sizeof(MyStack<T, C>), "Size mismatch.");
    static_assert(alignof s == alignof(MyStack<T, C>), "Alignment mismatch.");
    return static_cast<MyStack<T, C>&>(s).c;
}
```

Comment: It's a `protected` member, so no it's not "accessible". Though you can hack around that if you're desperate.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Maxim's answer (not enough rep to comment):

`std::stack` doesn't have a virtual destructor, so attempting to `delete` `MyStack` from a base-class pointer to `std::stack` is unsafe. You can decide to trust that your compiler will generate warnings in these cases, or use private inheritance to prevent this scenario in most cases.

```
template<class T, class C>
struct MyStack : private std::stack<T, C> 
{
    typedef std::stack<T, C> Stack;
    using Stack::Stack;
    using Stack::operator=;
    using Stack::c; // expose as public
    // Private inheritance, explicitly forward functions we need
    using Stack::size;
    using Stack::push;
    using Stack::pop;
    // etc
};
```